# How do you group values in SQL Server Report Builder 2014

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I am trying to replicate the group function in Excel, through SSR. I have tried grouping in report builder, & the following expression.

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Age.Value)<21,"Under 21",(IIF(First(Fields!Age.Value)>=21 AND First(Fields!Age.Value)<=50,"Between 21 and 50","Over 50")))
```

I will actually need a lot more groups than this, but was trialing this out to ensure it works. The principle is good, in regards to it re naming the columns with the corresponding group.. i.e `17>21` fall into `Under 21` but I still have 5 rows of data whereas I would like only one row with sum of `under 21` etc.

what I am looking for -

```
 Age    Count
under21  1
22-30    2
31-40    1
41-50    4 
51-60    11
61-70    9
71+      18
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are separate columns for each group:

For your **Under 21** column, the expression would be:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Age.Value < 21, 1, 0) )
```

For **21 - 30**, use:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Age.Value >= 21 AND Fields!Age.Value <= 30, 1, 0) )
```

And so on. The downside is that you need to create a separate one for each age group. Luckily we don't live too long.

Now that I re-read your question, it looks like you already have it the way you want. Are you just need to use `=CountRows()` for the number in the group?

Comment: Hi @Hannover Fist, I ended up re writing the actual query in SSMS, but your answer definitely looks like it would have worked. Thanks :)